# Ember.HTMLBars.compile is undefined in Ember 2.7

Tags: ember.js, htmlbars

In our application we use the template compiler at runtime by calling `Ember.HTMLBars.compile` with a handlebars template. Example code:

```
let myTemplate = `{{foo}}`;
application.register(`template:my-template`, Ember.HTMLBars.compile(myTemplate));
```

I've tried to upgrade from Ember 2.6 to Ember 2.7 but I get the following error in the developer console if I try to compile the template:

> _ember.default.HTMLBars.compile is not a function()

In the documentation I couldn't find anything about the compile method being removed from the HTMLBars compiler.

How can I still use/enable the HTMLBars compiler at runtime in my application?

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import original `ember-template-compiler.js` in `ember-cli-build.js`

```
app.import('bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js');
```

Comment: For the latest version of Ember: `app.import('node_modules/ember-source/dist/ember-template-compiler.js')`

Answer (score 1):

I was needed to compile template during runtime 
und used https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-handlebars-inline-precompile.
Try this:

```
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';
application.register(`template:my-template`, hbs`{{foo}}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Since there is less information provided, first try and check the error source.**

presumably a library it is, you need to open your developers console [lets say chrome]  and then click on the error which will direct you to where the error originates from so you can adjust or rectify the code...

Comment: The question is about how to resolve the error (which I found in the developer console). The point is that HTMLBars doens't provide the method compile anymore (in Ember 2.7.0) which it did before (Ember 2.6.2)